Programming Error in MySQL LOAD DATA statement when using ENCLOSED BY
I am trying to run a SQL statement using cursor.execute
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'/home/ubuntu/test.csv'
INTO TABLE app_data
CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS ENCLOSED BY ""
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

This runs using mysql command line but the ENCLOSED BY raises a ProgrammingError / OperationalError.
Any help/pointers appreciated. I have already tried variations such as ENCLOSED BY '"'.

Share the full code that triggers the error. Likely the " is interpreted by Python itself.

Thanks @willeM_VanOnsem. I reordered the IGNORE 1 rows and ENCLOSED BY and it started working.

What does ENCLOSED BY "" should mean? Maybe you want ENCLOSED BY '"'?or ENCLOSED BY ''?

'I reordered the IGNORE 1 rows and ENCLOSED BY and it started working.' - there is no IGNORE in the published code...

@P.Salmon you are correct. I edited my question.

@Akina you are correct.. Looks wrong but MySQL accepts it. I think it is the same as "
